# ng-change AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Dentro de una etiqueta select tengo una lista de números (minutos) las cuales al ser seleccionado muestra como resultado una nueva lista con rango de horas entre las 08:00:00 y 09:00:00

por ejemplo si se selecciona el numero 10 la lista a mostrar tendrá el siguiente resultado 08:00:00 - 08:10:00, 08:10:00 - 08:20:00 ....... 08:50:00 - 09:00:00

Siempre se muestra el rango dependiendo el numero de minutos seleccionados. Para ello he utilizado lo siguiente:

vista html

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-50">
    <div class="item item-input item-select">
      <div class="input-label positive">
           Tiempo
      </div>
      <select ng-change="ngChange()" ng-model="mm" ng-options="mm.minuto as mm.minuto for mm in numeros">
          <option value="">Tiempo</option>
      </select>                 
    </div> 
   </div>
   <div class="col col-50">
      <h4 ng-repeat="a in ran"> ({{a.h}}) </h4>
   </div>  
</div>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.horario1="08:00:00";
  $scope.horario2="09:00:00";
  var s = moment($scope.horario1, 'H:mm:ss');
  var e = moment($scope.horario2, 'H:mm:ss');
  $scope.ran = [];
  $scope.numeros = [{ minuto: 10 }, { minuto: 20 }, { minuto: 30 }];

  var  rango=function(s, e, minutes){
    var range = [];
    for(var hour = moment(s); hour.isBefore(e); hour.add(minutes, 'minutes') ){
      range.push(moment(hour));
    }
    range.push(moment(e));
    return range;
  }

  $scope.ngChange = function () {
    var varRangos = rango(s, e, $scope.mm);
    for(var p = 0; p < varRangos.length-1; p++){
      var hora=moment(varRangos[p]).format('HH:mm:ss');
      var hora2=moment(varRangos[p+1]).format('HH:mm:ss');
      $scope.ran.push({h:hora+' - '+hora2});
    }
  }
```

Este codigo funciona de forma correcta PERO al momento de mostrar en la lista se me acumulan los rangos; es decir si presiono 10 en primera instancia se muestra la lista con el rango de diez, pero si presiono 20 o 30 a esa lista se acumulan y el resultado muestra la lista con todos los rangos.

Como puedo arreglar ese problema?

Finalmente como puedo hacer que por defecto el rango sea 10 y que al iniciar la aplicación me muestre la lista con las horas con rango 10

Espero me haya hecho entender de antemano les agradezco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto sucede por que no estas limpiando la lista antes de agregar los datos, para que funcione el metodo `$scope.ngChange` debe quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
  $scope.ngChange = function () {
    var varRangos = rango(s, e, $scope.mm);
    $scope.ran = []; // se limpia el arreglo para agregar la nueva información
    for(var p = 0; p < varRangos.length-1; p++){
      var hora=moment(varRangos[p]).format('HH:mm:ss');
      var hora2=moment(varRangos[p+1]).format('HH:mm:ss');
      $scope.ran.push({h:hora+' - '+hora2});
    }
  }
```

Comment: Gracias Amigo ha sido algo tan simple que me ha ayudado mucho